# Не добавляются элементы в бд

Tags: c#, .net

Application User

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Todo> Todos { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Category

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public List<Todo> Todos { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Метод добавляет категорию в бд, но её нельзя получить из ApplicationUser

[HttpPost]
public async Task AddCategory(string categoryName)
{
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(HttpContext.User.Identity!.Name);

```
    var a = await _db.Users.FindAsync(user.Id);
    
    await _db.Categories.AddAsync(new Category()
    {
        Name = categoryName,
        ApplicationUser = a
    });

    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> GetAll()
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(HttpContext.User.Identity!.Name);
    return _db.Users.FindAsync(user.Id).Result!.Categories;
}
```

Comment: а в базе она появляется?

Comment: в таблице категории да, но в AspNetUser Categories пустые

Comment: у вас 2 таблицы категорий? Вы в одну добавляете, из другой читаете?

Comment: если вам нужны категории, зачем вообще запрашивать юзеров? Нельзя это `return _db.Users.FindAsync(user.Id).Result!.Categories;` заменить на что то типа `return await _db,Categories.Where(c=>c.AppUser.Id == user.Id).ToListAsync();` ?

Answer (score 0):

У вас нет в коде добавления категории в список категорий пользователя, измените код например на:

```
var a = await _db.Users.FindAsync(user.Id);

var newCategory = new Category()
{
    Name = categoryName,
    ApplicationUser = a
};

await _db.Categories.AddAsync(newCategory);
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

// Добавление новой категории в список категорий пользователя
a.Categories.Add(newCategory);
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```